# Looking to send sms from rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, sms

I want to be able to send a text (sms) message I have a User and Post model in my app. A post belongs to a User and User has many posts. I also have a mobile field in Users as well as all the standard address, zip etc..

Admins can also create a post for a user. On the creation of a post for a specific user by the admin, I want that user to be able to receive an SMS saying that your post has been created and the contents of that post too. Does anyone know how I can achieve this and any good free API's?

Comment: Check this one really cool thing, my friends still use it  https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages

Answer (score 1):

Twilio is really cool come with great support. :+1:

Here is the tutorial how to send SMSs with Twilio. https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/sms

Comment: That's some pretty cool stuff, I saw some amazing things but it runs with Sinatra and when I research what that is, it's basically a domain specific platform for creating rails apps fast. This guy doesn't create it in a rails framework rather in just 1 file. But if u wanted to use Sinatra and Twilio inside a rails app, firstly Can I? Secondly where would  all the coding logic go in my model?

Comment: Twilio offers `twilio` gem with PORO approach so you can use it in any framework. Take a look at this: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby

Answer (score 0):

Try [textris gem](https://github.com/visualitypl/textris).

It has sms, and much more cool stuff.